# Loop cutting parts of an object instead of the whole object in Edit Mode

Tags: modeling

I have the below objects in two different versions of a blender file I'm working on. However when I click loop cut in Edit Mode with nothing selected, in one version (left image) I can cut the object as a whole. In the other (right image), it allows me only to cut parts of the object. I'm not sure why.

[image: loop cutting whole object on left but part on right]

I read one post that indicates I can only use loop cut when an object has four faces, however mine has the ribbon in the middle and on the left version cuts fine.

Can someone explain why this is the case? Sometimes loop cut allows me to cut an object in half all the way around and sometimes not.

Comment: did you remove the doubles in the second picture? W-->remove doubles in edit mode

Comment: Yes, I did it.  I have to tell you when I extrude to make the ribbon I used E and S.